# C# MySQL - "Update" is selecting every row/everything

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql

My issue is that everytime I try to update in my CMS, it simply updates EVERY column / row.
For example:
I update `Test 1 -> Test 2`

Meanwhile I have Test 4

But then Test 4 -> Test 2 due to I changed Test 1 to 2 it simply changes that aswell.

They still work by ID correctly, and when I delete them, they delete individually, so the only function that is overlapping with everything is update.

I will now post my code (this is what I have learned, do not comment on security or w/e) simply need this issue fixed so it only updates the selected ID row.

First:

```
    public DataRow GetById(string ID)
{

    strSQL = "SELECT ID, clnOverskrift, clnTekst "
          + "FROM tblForside "
          + "WHERE ID=@ID";

    objCMD = new MySqlCommand(strSQL);
    objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);

    return objData.GetData(objCMD, objCon).Rows[0];
}
public void Update(PropertyForside Pro)
{

    strSQL = "UPDATE tblForside SET "
             + " clnOverskrift=@Overskrift, clnTekst=@Tekst ";

    objCMD = new MySqlCommand(strSQL);
    objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Overskrift", Pro.Overskrift);
    objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tekst", Pro.Tekst);

    objData.ModifyData(objCMD, objCon);
}
```

I will use both GetById and Update thats why I included both.
if you need to know more in this "factory" i will post it.

Here i get it:

```
    FactoryForside fac = new FactoryForside();
PropertyForside Pro = new PropertyForside();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        DataRow dr = fac.GetById(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

        txtOverskrift.InnerText = dr["clnOverskrift"].ToString();
        txtText.InnerText = dr["clnTekst"].ToString();
    }
}
protected void btnGem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Pro.Overskrift = txtOverskrift.InnerText;
    Pro.Tekst = txtText.InnerText;
    Pro.ID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

    fac.Update(Pro);

    Response.Redirect("RedigerForside.aspx");
}
```

I use InnerText to use TextAreas with NiceEdit.

Adding new ones work, and deleting as mentioned before - only this updating thing not working correctly.
It displays ID correctly `"EditForside.aspx?id=13"` in the browser, but it seems to select every other ID aswell

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UPDATE statement has to include a WHERE condition - the same you use in your select. Then it will update only that particular row. Without a WHERE it updates every row in the table.

Documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: THANK YOU.

I mean.. This is one of the most basic things, and I missed it.

I am *********

Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be because you have not provided the `where` condition in your `update` clause. So if you dont provide a `where` condition in your `update` statement it would end up updating every row of your table.

Try something like this:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE tblForside SET "
         + " clnOverskrift=@Overskrift, clnTekst=@Tekst "
         + " WHERE ID=@ID";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a `WHERE` clause in your update statement.  E.g.

```
strSQL = "UPDATE tblForside SET "
         + " clnOverskrift=@Overskrift, clnTekst=@Tekst "
         + " WHERE ID=@ID";
```

This limits which rows will be updated.